# Reverse .scrollTop():

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking to scroll back up a `div` using the <kbd>Up</kbd> key.

I have...

```
if(e.keyCode == 38) {
    var y = $("section").scrollTop();
    $("section").animate({
        scrollTop: (y + i++)
    }, 500);
}
```

which is working fine with the <kbd>Down</kbd> key to scroll down the `div`.

Any ideas on how how to reverse this code so the `div` would scroll to the top? Is this even possible?

Comment: are you sure that code is for the down arrow? keycode = 38 means the up arrow.

Comment: Try using `scrollTop: (y - i++)`

Comment: scrollTop: (y - i++) worked! Geez I should have known that! :) Thanks!